# sqlite error :/* SQLITE MISUSE */ error ios - Add Table

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am trying to insert values into new table added, my development app works fine whereas, my testing app its giving error `SQLITE MISUSE` when inserting data to new table, when i check the sqlite file it contains that table, but if i have app without login then try to login again, it works fine, i am not understanding why SQLITE MISUSE error, in this case update will not work.

Add Table :

```
    createSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE if not exists [%@] (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title text, description text, favourite text, template text, modified_date text)", NEW_TABLE];
    if (sqlite3_exec (database, [createSQL UTF8String],NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSLog(@"Error in creating Inbox table: %s",errorMsg);
    }
```

Insert :

```
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int sqlError;
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ (title, description, favourite, template, modified_date) values (?,?,?,?,?)", NEW_TABLE];
    const char *zSql = [query UTF8String];
    sqlError = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, zSql, -1, &stmt, nil);
    if (sqlError == SQLITE_OK) {
        // insert data
    } else {
        DLog(@"Error - %d while preparing startement - %@", sqlError, query);
    }
```

Comment: What does "i have app without login then try to login again" mean?  Logging into what?  How's is it relevant to the database table?  Also learn how to report errors properly (i.e. using `sqlite3_errmsg()`).

Comment: thanks for the `sqlite3_errmsg`. without login means there are two cases - app already logged in and second where already user has not logged in earlier version of testing app.

Comment: The "MISUSE" error comes when you misuse the API. Here's what you must check. Each time you call `sqlite3_open_v2` you must eventually call `sqlite3_close` before you try to open again. For every call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` you must call `sqlite3_finalize` with 0 or more uses of `sqlite3_reset` on the prepared statement.